# How to communicate with strange HID?

Tags: c#, windows, hid

I am using a MSR reader (MSR250HK), which is HID device with particular VID and PID. That device on swipe card event immediately fires the read date into a text field no matter what you do.

When I learned that its a HID device, I tried various libraries for communication with the device

like HIDLibrary, some libs on Codeproject, even here on stackoverflow suggestion
but the result was:
doesn't connect the device or fires the read data immediately, without activating the read events from the libraries

Comment: From my experience with Magnetic Stripe Readers, they're treated no differently to keyboards - except they type a little faster!

Comment: So you are saying to treat the MSR as keyboard to keylog the input and do whatever I want, right?